# Finding masses of the products for halogenation of benzene from percent yields

Tags: stoichiometry

> We provide a reactor $\pu{90 kg}$ of benzene and $\pu{30 kg}$ of $\ce{Cl2}$.If the percent yield of the first reaction with respect to benzene is $25\,\%,$ and the percent yield of the second reaction with respect to benzene is $2\,\%,$ which are the total final masses of chlorobenzene and dichlorobenzene?

This was a question in a test of mine, which I got wrong. In my opinion there were two ways to interpret this problem, that led to two different results.

We want to produce chlorobenzene using the following reaction:

$$\ce{C6H6 + Cl2 -> C6H5Cl + HCl}\label{rxn:R1}\tag{R1}$$

However, the following undesired reaction occurs simultaneously, giving dichlorobenzene:

$$\ce{C6H6 + 2 Cl2 -> C6H4Cl2 + 2 HCl}\label{rxn:R2}\tag{R2}$$

I computed the amounts $n(\ce{C6H6}) = \pu{1154 mol}$ and $n(\ce{Cl2}) = \pu{414 mol}.$ The limiting reagent is chlorine for both reactions: in \eqref{rxn:R1} the ratio between $\ce{C6H6}$ and $\ce{Cl2}$ should be $1:1$ according to \eqref{rxn:R1} and $1:2$ for \eqref{rxn:R2}.

The first reaction theoretically should produce $\pu{414 mol}$ of $\ce{C6H5Cl},$ but since its percent yield with reference to benzene is only $25\,\%,$ only $\pu{414 mol}\times 0.25 = \pu{103.5 mol}$ of benzene react, which produces $\pu{103.5 mol}$ of $\ce{C6H5Cl}.$

In the second reaction only $\pu{207 mol}$ of benzene should react given the $\pu{414 mol}$ of $\ce{Cl2},$ but since its percent yield with reference to benzene is $2\,\%,$ we get that only $\pu{207 mol}\times 0.02 = \pu{4.14 mol}$ of benzene react, which produces $\pu{4.14 mol}$ of $\ce{C6H4Cl2}.$ The rest is just converting amounts to masses.

My professor said I had to compute the $25\,\%$ of the original $\pu{1154 mol}$ of benzene, and that quantity $(\pu{288.5 mol})$ of benzene is the one that reacts in the first reaction. Same for the second reaction, giving $\pu{1153 mol}\times 0.02 = \pu{23.06 mol}$ of benzene which react in \eqref{rxn:R2}.

Which approach would be the correct one?

Comment: There's no two ways, you probably calculated how much benzene was converted to each halide when you needed masses of halides themselves.

Comment: Useful links for text and formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) // Use plain texts in CH SE titles. // For more, see [Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: 414 mol is molar amount of chlorine not benzene. BTW, we do not say number of moles nor number of kilograms.

Comment: Consider these 4 slightly different terms: 1/ Reaction yield with 1 product. 2/ Reaction yields with 2 parallel products. 3/ Reaction yields with 2 parallel products wrt excessive reactant A. 4/ Reaction yields with 2 parallel products wrt deficit reactant B.